# IndexError: list assignment index out of range when using custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I execute the following code, I'm getting `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`:

```
def tcheb (a,b,n):
    V=[]
    for j in range(1,n) :
        for k in range (1,n):
                V[k]=((a+b)/2) + (((a-b)/2) * (np.cos((k-1)/(n-1)*np.pi)))
        return V.append(k)
tcheb(-5,5,2)
```

Comment: you're trying to assign to `V[k]`, but `V` has length == 0

Comment: Also, `return V.append(k)` will return `None`, since `list.append` modifies the list in-place and doesn't return any value

Comment: What output do you expect? That loop looks like it will exit early.

Answer (score 0):

a = [0] * 10 is how you  initialize a sized list

```
def tcheb (a,b,n):
    V=[0] * 10
    for j in range(1,n) :
        for k in range (1,n):
                V[k]=((a+b)/2) + (((a-b)/2) * (np.cos((k-1)/(n-1)*np.pi)))
        return V.append(k)
tcheb(-5,5,2)
```